# How can I get rid of the '“Visual Studio Code” is an app downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?' message?

Tags: applications

I just installed VSCode on macOS latest (Mojave 10.14.5) and **every time** I open it I get a popup saying:

> “Visual Studio Code” is an app downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?

This app was downloaded from the internet and it is installed in my Applications folder. I have clicked the 'Open' button every time and still it pops up like this.

Is there a way to not have that happen? I followed the regular install instructions and I don't have this problem on my other Macbook Pro ... not sure what is going on.

Comment: @fsb -- thank you for that link but it seems that that rather is about some custom Xcode app. This is for VS Code from Microsoft so I don't understand why even an app from a vetted developer is having this problem.

Comment: Did you try `sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio*` ?

Comment: I've removed the video, it doesn't add additional information.